# dataTables automatic linebreak in cell

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a boostrap modal with a dataTables-table in it. I have a issue where cells with content with no spaces or linebreaks increases the width of the tables outside of the modal.

How can i fix this? See image below

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try applying the following css to the cell:

```
word-break:break-all;
```

Check [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xjfh3ys/)

If that doesn't work for you ... try working with [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

```
white-space: normal;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the dataTables api? I add my rows with a loop calling: oDetailsTableAPI.row.add([value.key, value.value]).draw();

Comment: check default styling options for that at: http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/classes

Comment: you can apply classes to specific columns also on datatables initialization ... inside paramenter columns (or aoColumns) assign parameter class (or sClass) depending on DT version. Search here for sClass for live examples http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

Answer (score 1):

Add  `white-space:normal;` style to the **Varde** column.

```
<table class="datatable-init table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Detaij</th>
        <th>Varde</th>
        </tr>
    <thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td style="white-space:normal;"></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```